# При запуске скрипта на python стандартный ввод равен None. sys.stdin = None

Tags: python, stdin

Есть простой скрипт на питоне, который запускается через zabbix типом External check.
Операционная система Oracle linux

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import daemon
import sys
from traceback import format_exc


def run_main_function():
    print("Hello")

try:
    with daemon.DaemonContext():
        run_main_function()
except:
    print(sys.stdin)
    print(format_exc())
```

```
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/zabbix/externalscripts/logstash_stats.py", line 18, in <module>
    with daemon.DaemonContext():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/daemon/daemon.py", line 249, in __init__
    detach_process = is_detach_process_context_required()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/daemon/daemon.py", line 817, in is_detach_process_context_required
    if is_process_started_by_init() or is_process_started_by_superserver():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/daemon/daemon.py", line 795, in is_process_started_by_superserver
    if is_socket_file(sys.__stdin__):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/daemon/daemon.py", line 759, in is_socket_file
    file_fd = file.fileno()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fileno'
```

Сначало я грешил на библиотеку daemon. Но, если запустить скрипт ниже, то увидим, что sys.stdin = None. А библиотеке daemon нужен корректный stdin, который создаётся при запуске скрипта.

```
import sys

print(sys.stdin)
```

return:

```
None
```

Права скрипту выданы, но не понятно почему с вероятностью 20% скрипт выдаёт ошибку, а остальные 80% отрабатывает успешно.

```
chown zabbix:zabbix /path/script
chmod 0777 /path/scrypt
```

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема и как её побороть?

Comment: Укажите, что за библиотека, откуда ее брали. Я нахожу https://pypi.org/project/daemon/, но там в модуле 118 строк, явно не та библиотека. Попробуйте еще вот это, например https://github.com/thesharp/daemonize. Все похожие библиотеки, какие нахожу, не очень-то живые, но может повезет.

Comment: P.S. я предполагаю, что это баг в библиотеке, но чтобы это подтвердить, нужно как минимум знать, что это за библиотека, где ее взять, чтобы посмотреть код или воспроизвести ошибку.

Comment: Библиотека используется https://pypi.org/project/python-daemon/

Comment: Может это и баг в библиотеке, но библиотека явно хочет получить sys.stdin.fileno(). Но так как sys.stdin возвращает None, поэтому возникает ошибка. Причина не в библиотеке. Не понятно почему stdin равен None. Решив эту проблему не будет ошибок. Но я не понимаю это явление

Comment: Вот то что она хочет получить stdin.fileno, не проверив, что stdin != None - это и есть баг.

Comment: В общем, вот тут кроме ValueError должно быть еще AttributeError: https://pagure.io/python-daemon/blob/main/f/daemon/daemon.py#_758

Comment: Вот даже свежее issue с точно такой же ситуацией: https://pagure.io/python-daemon/issue/89

Comment: @insolor И там есть такой комментарий: "This seems like the correct behaviour when this unusual circumstance
happens; the program is in a very unusual state (the `sys.__stdin__` should
never be modified from its original value), and crashing with a message to
inform of this, seems appropriate." То есть всё-таки нужно выяснять, откуда в `stdin` взялся `None`, а не патчить либу.

Comment: @CrazyElf как бы да, но я не вижу причин не пропатчить. Дебажить, почему в 20% случаев stdin равен None можно долго.

Comment: Вот похожее https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17458728/when-is-sys-stdin-none-in-python

Comment: а редиректа нет при запуске из заббикс по типу ```python script.py < input_file.txt```?

Comment: @falm Редиректа нет. Вот выражение с zabbix scrypt.py["-s","{HOST.HOST}","-t","60"]

Comment: @Сергей Кох , Видел, это не помогло. Любое ручное переопределение stdin  не дает результата.
Я имею ввиду, что stdin то я установлю, но библиотека daemon все равно работать не будет.

Comment: Как костыль попробуйте `sys.stdin = open(os.devnull)` (sys и os импортировать нужно). `sys.stdin = os.devnull` не сработает, потому что os.devnull - это строка, а нужен файловый объект.

Comment: @insolor, Спасибо, это для меня работает.

`sys.stdin = open(os.devnull); sys.__stdin__ = sys.stdin`

Честно я не очень хотел менять daemon.py , но если бы это было единственное решение для меня, я бы это сделал.
До вашего совета выставить  sys.stdin = open(os.devnull) я использовал такую конструкцию, но она для меня не работала. В чем принципиальная разница можете объяснить?

`setattr(sys, _name, open(os.devnull, 'r' if _name == 'stdin' else 'w', encoding="UTF-8"))  ; sys.__stdin__ = sys.stdin`

Comment: Ну, вы что-то переусложнили. stdin всегда только на чтение работает. setattr не понятно тоже зачем так вызывать, достаточно простого присваивания. Кодировку тут указывать не обязательно, потому что devnull никогда ничего не выдает.

Comment: На самом деле я просто перебирал все варианты в гугл, включая этот https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17458728/when-is-sys-stdin-none-in-python.
Я даже делал так `sys.stdin = open("/etc/zabbix/file.txt")`, но это тоже не работало  . А теперь я понимаю почему не работало, потому что важно еще вставить `sys.__stdin__ = sys.stdin` . Спасибо вам всем большое за помощь в решении проблемы.  @insolor вам отдельный плюс в карму за рабочий костыль и выявление источника проблемы=)